# Publishing to AIR Captive Runtime ONLY creates .tmp folder

Tags: air, runtime, flash-cs6

Having a recurring issue when trying to create an AIR Captive Runtime using the latest AIR 3.5 SDK.

Publishing in Windows 7 from Flash CS6.

Most of the time AIR will only create a .tmp folder and NOT an .app folder

And the .exe in the .tmp folder sometimes works, other times gives an error message on launch saying a wrong version of air exists.
At other times the .tmp folder is totally empty.

Anyone PLEASE with any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running into this problem again, I found that the actual solution is:

1) EDIT the adobe air application descriptor xml file for the project, make sure the following tag is uncommented and includes the extendedDesktop profile:

<supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>

2) Clean your project

3) Then export release build from flexbuilder and select captive runtime option.

The solution listed below was misleading (I had actually included the step described above and not included it in my description below ). Command Line execution was a red herring.

I solved my problem by using a command line request and following the instructions at [this website](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/08/bundling-air-3-runtime-in-air-desktop-applications/).

Executing the command line request from the bin-release temp folder on my machine I modified the following to my desktop settings:

```
c:\path\to\air3sdk\bin\adt.bat -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore c:\path\to\certificate.p12 -target bundle myapp.exe myapp-app.xml -C . myapp.swf
```